# Assets in espresso breaks my app

Tags: ruby

Here is my simple app:

```
class Blog < E
  map '/'

  # actions goes here
end

app = EApp.new do

  # assets_url '/', true

  mount Blog
end

app.run server: :Thin, Port: 6040
```

It works well until i uncomment `assets_url '/', true`.

If i do so, all my routes returning 404 and only routes pointing to files in assets folder works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks correct except assets URL.

You are mounting your app and assets server on same URL - `/`

Assets server has precedence, thus your app routes wont work.

Simply mount your assets on a corresponding URL, `/assets`, `/static`, `/etc`

```
app = EApp.new do

  assets_url '/assets', true

  mount Blog
end
```

UPDATE: as of version 0.4.6, assets server moved to [Espresso Lungo](https://github.com/espresso/espresso-lungo)

So install `el` gem - `$ gem in el` - or add it to `Gemfile` - `gem "el"`

Comment: So obvious... how could i miss that, Thanks.

Comment: @slivu As of today this doesn't work. Would you please update the answer?