# serving static files with Ruby Espresso

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to serve some assets using the el gem but can't seem to get it to work. I've referred to another question posted here -- [Assets in espresso breaks my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730406/assets-in-espresso-breaks-my-app/13730964#comment23765139_13730964)

My setup looks like this --

```
require 'e'
require 'el'
...

app = E.new(true){  
    assets_url '/pub', true
}
```

But hitting localhost:5252/pub/hello.txt (yes, this file exists) results in 404. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to append any paths to Sprockets environment.

http://espresso.github.io/Periphery/Assets.html#sprockets

Please try:

```
app = E.new(true){  
  assets_url '/pub', true
  assets.append_path 'relative-path-to-static-files'
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks once again slivu!

Comment: Oops, sorry, spoke too soon. Still not resolved as I now see this instead -- undefined method `assets_url' for #<EBuilder:...

Comment: Yup, that was it! Thanks again!